# How to interrupt a thread if it is to open socket?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I have tried to close the current thread that is a part of multi-threading server. 
The thread is ready to open the socket that may be accessed by clients.

**Everything works fine except when the code below is contained in while() loop.**

> new ServerThread(serversocket.accept(), this.Rstr,
>   bag.numberofDatatoAcquire).start();

Here is the code for the server:

```
public void run() {

    System.out.println("This has been called ");   

    try{

       System.out.println("This has been tried");    
       serversocket = new ServerSocket(this.iPort);                                 

       Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();

       while(!thisThread.isInterrupted()){
           new ServerThread(serversocket.accept(), this.Rstr, bag.numberofDatatoAcquire).start();
           //sending socket accessed, where it will store the data and how much it will collect it.                            
           System.out.println("This has been running");                  
           Thread.sleep(10);               
       }           
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        //why bother? it is an usual happening...lol
    }catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.err.println("Can't open the socket on port");               
    }
    finally{     
       System.out.println("Thread is dead and ready for change");
    }
}
```

And this is a part of GUI events: this works well without "new ServerThread..." code.

```
private OverWatch EW = new OverWatch(bag.iPortOrder, bag.SessionAcquisitionSavingDirectory);   

....

private void OverWatcherControl(boolean checker)
{
    if(checker)
        EW.start();  
    else
        EW.interrupt();

}
```

Since the variable bag.numberofDataToAcquire (public integer type) is supposed to be changed whenever user wants, I think I have to stop this thread and change the variable then run this thread again. Am I wrong? Or how can I interrupt this thread?

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly happens when this code is "contained in a while loop"?

Comment: It can't interrupt the thread and I can't see the message "Thread is dead.."

Comment: Do you have a timeout set for server.accept? If not, it will wait until it gets packets forever; this may be your problem.

Comment: FYI: I've edited my answer to show how your can use `ServerSocketChannel` to accept which gets interrupted by a call to `thread.interrupt()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ServerSocket.accept()` is a blocking call that is not responsive to thread interruption. Almost all the `java.net` blocking calls (connect, read, accept, etc) do not respond to Thread.interrupt(). This behavior is "as designed".

A way to wake up a thread blocked in `.accept()` or `.read()` is to close the underlying socket.

Alternatively you could set SO_TIMEOUT (`setSoTimeout`) on the ServerSocket, which will cause `.accept()` to wake up periodically by throwing a `SocketTimeoutException`.  You could catch that exception and use it as an opportunity to check the interrupt status on the thread.

The `java.nio` package (Java 1.4+) provides an alternate sockets API that is more responsive to interruption.

Comment: I have never thought about SocketTimeoutException!!! Thanks!!! I have to use it right now!!!

Comment: You mentioned this java.net behavior is "as designed". Do you have more details about why it was designed that way. I did a quick search but couldn't find any motivation behind this behavior.

Answer (score 7):

Just as an *alternative* to using a timeout or killing the socket:

*Fake* a new connection to the socket. This will "wake up" the `accept()` and then an additional signaling mechanism (e.g. flag or interrupt check) can be used (although the logic would have to be altered slightly from shown to not "lie" in the `println`).

I have used this approach before and it worked well: no need to wait for a timeout (even a sort one) or handle another exception and the socket remains open/valid (which may or may not be desired). On the other hand, I'm not sure what would happen on a *really long/broken* TCP handshake, but that's a case I never encountered ;-)

Happy coding.

Comment: +1 for getting the blocking call to return by opening a connection from the thread that wants it to return.

Answer (score 2):

I initially answered it using the `serverSocket.setSoTimeout(millis)` and handling the `SocketTimeoutException`.  See below.

A better way to do it would be to use `ServerSocketChannel` which gets interrupted in the `accept()` call when you call `thread.interrupt()` so you don't have to spin at all.  So you'd do something like:

```
ServerSocketChannel socketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
socketChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(this.iPort), 10);
...
while (! thisThread.isInterrupted()) {
    // channel accepts _are_ interrupted by the call to thread.interrupt()
    // it throws ClosedByInterruptException when interrupt() is called
    SocketChannel accepted = socketChannel.accept();
    new ServerThread(accepted.socket(), this.Rstr,
        bag.numberofDatatoAcquire).start();
}
```

---

I'll take a whack at explaining the code:

```
while(!thisThread.isInterrupted()){
   new ServerThread(serversocket.accept(), this.Rstr,
        bag.numberofDatatoAcquire).start();
   Thread.sleep(10);               
}
```

I think your problem here is that `serversocket.accept()` *hangs* waiting for a socket to be accepted.  From the [`accept()` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29):

> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts  it. The method blocks until a connection is made.

You need to set a timeout on your socket before the `while` loop.  You can use [`setSoTimeout(millis)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) for that.

```
serversocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
```

This will then throw a `SocketTimeoutException` if it times out.  Then you won't need the `Thread.sleep(10)` (which is for 10ms btw) because the sleeping will be done inside of the `accept()` method.  I would *not* recommend `accept(10)` because that would spin pretty aggressively.

Comment: OK, it is hanging there...I see. But I will need the sleep() method otherwise I can't use interrupt. It says InterruptException is never thrown. And I wish to close this thread even before it accept clients.

Comment: You don't need the catch then.  Just remove it.  `isInterrupted()` is a condition set on the thread when you call `interrupt()` on it.